# How to get the Gasprice during transaction in Ethereum using Web3.js?

Tags: web3js

I am trying to get the Gasprice during Ethereum trnsaction in Web3.js. The code is working properly, but I need to get the Gasprice during the transaction. Can you help to get the Gasprice?

Here is the code below:

```
const paymentAddress='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            
            Web3.eth.sendTransaction({
                to: paymentAddress,
                value: XXXXXXXXX
            }, (err, transactionId)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log("Error", err)
                    
                }else{
                    console.log("Successful", transactionId)
                    
                }
            }
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't set the `gasPrice` manually in the `sendTransaction()` function, it was set by the node that you're connected to.

You can retrieve the `gasPrice` value by transaction hash using the [getTransaction()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.0/web3-eth.html#gettransaction) function.

```
// with async/await
const tx = await web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionId);
console.log(tx.gasPrice);

// or with callback function
web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionId, (err, tx) => {
    console.log(tx.gasPrice)
})
```

Comment: But I am getting error as , await should be inside async , so where shall I insert the above code?

Comment: @Abhishek That's because you're using `await` outside of async function - that's related to JS programming in general, not to this specific `web3` library ... You can also use callback function instead of async/await - I just updated the answer with an example of this approach.

Comment: Thanks , the code worked. But I am getting three objects in the console like
c: [1500000010]
e:9
s:1
So, how to determine the gasprice from here?

Comment: @Abhishek I'm not sure what these output represent, it seems like it's some serialized object. You can find the expected output object (including the `gasPrice` property) in the [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.0/web3-eth.html#gettransaction).

Comment: Yes sir you are right. So getTransaction method is returning many data, among which I found 2 things, gas and gasPrice. So shall I have to multiply the gas with gasPrice to get the actual Price?

Comment: @Abhishek Yes - `gas` (amount of gas units consumed) multiplied by `gasPrice` (in wei) results in the number of wei (smallest unit of ETH) that you paid as the transaction fee.